# Whose portrait is it that appears in the Cache map's small room?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Today I played one of the iconic CSGO maps called Cache (*note: I haven't played this map since the rework.*) and there's one thing kinda hook me up. Who is this person whose photo appears in this small room?

To locate this photo, you just need to go to the B main and in front of the sun room, there's a small room on it.

[image]

Inside that room, it appear that there's a General's photo (I guess, since he has a lot of badges) hung up on the wall.

[image]

So who is this guy? Why does it appear in that room? Is he responsible for this mess? (I mean the Chernobyl disaster, since Cache is based on Pripyat, Ukraine.)

> The map takes place in Pripyat, Ukraine. The Chernobyl Power Plant is visible from the Terrorist spawn, along with nearby buildings and even fencing material consistent with the real-life counterpart.

Comment: medals, not badges (he also has ornate shoulder boards and collar/lapel markings, which implies higher rank)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Its a portrait of Vasily Alexandrovich Arkhipov, a Soviet Navy officer, who prevented a disastrous nuclear attack during the Cuban Missile Crisis in October 1962.

[Source](https://www.theloadout.com/csgo/cache-easter-egg-ww3)

[Vasily Arkhipov (vice admiral)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasily_Arkhipov_(vice_admiral)) on Wikipedia