# Whose portrait is it that appears in the Cache CT Spawn?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I was playing on the *CSGO* map called Cache and I noticed this family portrait. Who is this person or family? Is it one of the developers perhaps?

To locate this photo, you just need to go to the CT spawn of Cache and look left.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps related: [Whose portrait is it that appears in the Cache map's small room?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/371618/whose-portrait-is-it-that-appears-in-the-cache-maps-small-room) could possibly be his family photo?